# Udev rule for changing owner of Linux LVM device nodes

Tags: lvm, udev, device-mapper

I'm having some trouble changing the owner of a Linux LVM logical volume on my Debian wheezy system. I added the following udev rule to both the initramfs and the real root file system:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block",
ENV{DM_UUID}=="LVM-yYuoI8k05GWxZnz9BeEIwPUGGeojzF3dZZmXTYRqC051Tllj76OHdDlzYhKZUu7u",
OWNER="nikratio"
```

If I disable and re-enable this logical volume with *lvchange*, it gets
created with the correct owner.

However, when I boot the computer, the device always ends up being owned
by `root:disk` instead.

On the other hand, if I look at the permissions right before initramfs
executes the real init, the owner is actually correct (i.e., *nikratio*).

So, at some point between execution of the real init and completed
startup, something overwrites the owner of by device, but both before
and afterward the rule gets applied correctly.

Does anyone have an idea what's happening here? How can I get this to work?

Comment: Is a later udev rule changing it back perhaps?

Comment: What is the specific problem you are attempting to address?  In general, all disk stuff is generally owned by root for a good reason.

Comment: @mdpc: system is debian wheezy, as I said in the question :-). I need access to the block device so that ordinary users can use it as a qemu storage backend.

Comment: @Paul: yes, most likely, but I can't find any such rule...